# AttributeError: 'SearchEngine' object has no attribute 'ses'

Tags: python

I am trying to use the zipcodes package but was getting a ses error. Here is a brief snippt of my code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import zipfile
import io
import os
import pyproj
from shapely.ops import transform
from functools import partial
import json
from uszipcode import SearchEngine

search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
```

I am getting the following error

```
Exception ignored in: <function SearchEngine.__del__ at 0x7fcd6087eca0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/uszipcode/search.py", line 195, in __del__
    if self.ses:
AttributeError: 'SearchEngine' object has no attribute 'ses'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-325ac6f8df7d> in <module>
----> 1 search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
      2 search.ses.scalar(SimpleZipcode)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'simple_zipcode'
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Unless you are specifically asking about how to solve a cross-version compatibility problem (in which case your question should obviously describe that problem) you should not mix the [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] tags. I have deleted them both for the time being.

Comment: Have you checked https://uszipcode.readthedocs.io/uszipcode/search.html#uszipcode.search.SearchEngine? The first parameter to `SearchEngine()` is an enum, not a boolean.